# NIntegrate[] vs Integrate[]//N

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to find the numerical value of the following integral:
$$\int_0^2 \frac{\tan ^{-1}(x)}{x^2+2 x+2} \, dx$$
Using `NIntegrate` gives `0.256663`.

However the following code

```
Integrate[ArcTan[x]/(x^2 + 2 x + 2), {x, 0, 2}] // N
```

gives `0.256663 - 4.16334*10^-17 I`. 
What is going on?

Comment: The two versions are only equivalent when `Integrate` returns the integral unevaluated, i.e. when theres no analytic solution and `N` transforms it into a call to `NIntegrate`. In your example `Integrate` returns a fully symbolic solution though, and `N` merely approximates that expression, which turns out to contain a few complex valued terms which cancel fully symbolically but not numerically, where the residue due to rounding error and near cancellation can be seen. You can get rid of this by adding `//Chop` or calling `NIntegrate` directly.

Comment: Hi Rabie Hdaib, welcome to MmaSE, Please take the [tour]. Your question has been answered, and there are [things to do after that](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4). It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Comment: i appreciate your helpful comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The small imaginary part has nothing to do with the integration but when the antiderivative is evaluated. The reason is that the antiderivative that Mathematica finds is not optimal and contains many complex expression that *should* cancel out when you calculate the definite integral.

Let us check this:

```
fM[x_] = Integrate[ArcTan[x]/(x^2 + 2 x + 2), x]
fM[2.0] - fM[0.0]
(* 0.256663 + 1.66533*10^-16 I *)
```

This is what you observed. I mentioned that `fM[x]` is not *the best* antiderivative that can be found. A better one (if not the optimal) can be calculated using [Rubi](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/), the rule-based integrator.

```
fR[x_] = Int[ArcTan[x]/(x^2 + 2 x + 2), x]
```

If you compare the size of the antiderivatives of `fM[x]` and `fR[x]` you will find that the `LeafCount` for `fR` is 118, while Mathematica's result has 249. But this is not the only advantage. Look what we can do analytically with Rubi's result

```
FullSimplify[fR[2] - fR[0]]
(* 1/8 (π - 4 ArcCot[3]) ArcTan[2] *)
```

Looks nice and short, does it? And finally

```
N[%]
(* 0.256663 *)
```

The thing to be learned here is that when you have complex nested expression and you evaluate them numerically, there might be some imaginary left-overs that you can handle with `Chop`.

Finally, I want to mention that we are working heavily on making Rubi easily accessible on the [RuleBasedIntegration GitHub page](https://github.com/RuleBasedIntegration) because if Rubi can solve an integral, you can look at all steps that were required. For the moment, you can use the first Rubi link if you want to try it.

[image: img]

Comment: Thanks, this is crystal clear